# Recover ScopedModel without ScopedModelDescendant

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

In the docs from ScopedModel there is these instructions to retrieve a ScopedModel previosly created without ScopedModelDescendant. I don't realize if I could get rid from ScopedModelDescendant at all or I should declare it somewhere at last once?

From the docs:

> Finding the Model #
>
> There are two ways to find the Model provided by the ScopedModel
>   Widget.
>
> ```
> Use the ScopedModelDescendant Widget. It will find the Model and run the builder function whenever the Model notifies the listeners.
> Use the ScopedModel.of static method directly. To make this method more readable for frequent access, you can consider adding your own of
> ```
>
> method to your own Model classes like so:
>
> class CounterModel extends Model {   // ...
>       /// Wraps [ScopedModel.of] for this [Model].   static CounterModel of(BuildContext context) =>
>         ScopedModel.of(context); }

I wouldn't use ScopedModelDescendant, so I have instantiated the ScopedModel in the root:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<TeamModel>(
            model: TeamModel(widget._team),
            child: Container(
    ...
    ))
```

And I created a static method of as shown in the docs:

```
class TeamModel extends Model {


  static TeamModel of(BuildContext context){
    var of = ScopedModel.of<TeamModel>(context);
    return of;
  }
}
```

But I cannot retrieve the model inside my Container, it gives that famous error message:

```
22:38:41.603 11 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749): Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel.
22:38:41.603 12 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):     
22:38:41.603 13 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749): To fix, please:
22:38:41.603 14 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):           
22:38:41.604 15 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):   * Provide types to ScopedModel<MyModel>
22:38:41.604 16 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):   * Provide types to ScopedModelDescendant<MyModel> 
22:38:41.604 17 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):   * Provide types to ScopedModel.of<MyModel>() 
22:38:41.604 18 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 9749):   * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_model.dart';
```

It's not clear for me from the docs If I should use `ScopedModelDescendant` or else what is the problem with my code?

Comment: where do you call `TeamModel.of()` method?

Comment: It's descendant of that Container, inside build method from ListView.